# How to get the difference between current time and 15s forward in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `pandas DataFrame`, which stores stock price and time, time column's type is `pd.datetime`.

here is a demo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['2022-09-01 09:33:00', 100.], ['2022-09-01 09:33:14', 101.], ['2022-09-01 09:33:16', 99.4], ['2022-09-01 09:33:30', 100.9]], columns=['time', 'price'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
                 time  price
0 2022-09-01 09:33:00  100.0
1 2022-09-01 09:33:14  101.0
2 2022-09-01 09:33:16   99.4
3 2022-09-01 09:33:30  100.9
```

I want to calculate future return in 15s. (first price after 15 second - current price)

which I want is:

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
                 time  price  return
0 2022-09-01 09:33:00  100.0    -0.6  // the future price is 99.4, period is 16s
1 2022-09-01 09:33:14  101.0    -0.1  // the future price is 100.9, period is 16s
2 2022-09-01 09:33:16   99.4     NaN
3 2022-09-01 09:33:30  100.9     NaN
```

I know `df.diff` can get difference in index, is there any good methods can do this?

Comment: `df.loc[:, 'price'] = df[price].diff()`

Comment: you might also want to place `df = df.sort_values('time').reset_index()` before this

Comment: not simple diff in index, I want diff in time interval(15s) @Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `merge_asof` to the rescue

Subtract a timedelta of `15s` from the `right` dataframe then self merge on `time` using `merge_asof` with `direction=forward` which selects the first row in `right` dataframe whose on key is greater than or equal to the on key in the `left` dataframe then subtract the `price` column to calculate the `return`

```
df1 = pd.merge_asof(
    left=df,
    right=df.assign(time=df['time'] - pd.Timedelta('15s')),
    on='time', direction='forward', suffixes=['', '_r']
)

df1['return'] = df1.pop('price_r') - df1['price']
```

##### Result

```
                 time  price  return
0 2022-09-01 09:33:00  100.0    -0.6
1 2022-09-01 09:33:14  101.0    -0.1
2 2022-09-01 09:33:16   99.4     NaN
3 2022-09-01 09:33:30  100.9     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this (but I don't believe the output is very meaningful :-( ). Is it what you expected? (I realized this code assigned the return for the previous "15" seconds, not the next "15" seconds. But this is how the return is usually indexed - by the time when it is realized, not when it is still expected for the future).

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2022-09-01 09:33:00', 100.], ['2022-09-01 09:33:14', 101.], ['2022-09-01 09:33:16', 99.4], ['2022-09-01 09:33:30', 100.9]], columns=['time', 'price'])

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.sort_values('time').reset_index(drop=True)

df.loc[:, 'return'] = df['price'].diff()

df['time_diff'] = df['time'].diff()

df['15sec_or_more'] = (df['time_diff'] >= np.timedelta64(15, 's'))

for k, i in enumerate(df.index):
    if k:
        if not df.loc[i,'15sec_or_more']:
            temp = df.iloc[k:].loc[:,['return','time_diff']].cumsum(axis=0)
            conds = (temp['time_diff'] >= np.timedelta64(15, 's'))
            if conds.sum():
                true_return_index = conds.idxmax()
                df.loc[i, 'return'] = df.loc[true_return_index, 'return']
            else:
                df.loc[i, 'return'] = np.nan

df = df[['time', 'price' ,'return']]
print(df)
```